# Python Regex Confusion

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to debug this for some time but I don't appear to be making any progress.

Why does the regex below not match the text provided?

Regex:

```
'^(.*)============== TT ==============(.*)=================================================='
```

Text:

```
'fasdfdsfadf\ndfassdflj\n============== TT ==============\nPlease add.\n=================================================='
```

`re.search(x, editor_text)`

will return `None`

To my understanding the regex says return the first segment of text `(.*)` then look for the delimeter (===) and look for the 2nd segment of text `(.*)` and finish with delimeter.

Why does the regex not extract

`fasdfdsfadf\ndfassdflj\n`

and

`\nPlease add.\n`

Comment: afaik `.` __does not__ match newlines by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `s` (*dotall*) modifier which forces the dot to match newline sequences.

Using it as an [inline](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) modifier:

```
(?s)(.*)============== TT ==============(.*)==================================================
```

**Note:** You can simplify the regular expression as follows:

```
(?s)(.*)={14} TT ={14}(.*)={50}
```

Or including the flag inside your call to `re.search()`:

```
re.search(x, editor_text, re.S)
```

Comment: o i did not know you could use it like that... I always did `re.DOT_ALL` thats cool .... its neat when I learn new stuff :P

Comment: P.S. you don't need the `^` anchor here.

Comment: I still prefer to use re.DOTALL for its readability. (?iLmsux) always struck me as being a bit arcane.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag to match newline characters:

```
re.search(x, editor_text, re.DOTALL)
```